# Fade div out when script activates

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, fade

I am trying to fade out the media logos as soon as a JavaScript code activates.

http://rayku.com/start

When a user starts typing in the text box, a form comes up. At that moment, I'd like to have the media icons fade out.

Do you know how I can make that edit in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplier to just properly manage z-index of these elements?

Comment: The problem is not the z-index, but that the form has a transparent background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the logos are a background image of the form you won't be able to fade them out, but you can just set the background-image rule to "none".

Create a new css-class with the following content:

```
.theNewClass {background-image:none;}
```

Whenever a user enters something in the searchbox and the register form comes up, you add "theNewClass" to your register-form. When the register-form is dismissed you remove "theNewClass" from your register-form again and the logos will reappear.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery fadein() in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){

});
```

Comment: i think you ment 'fadeout', and if you allready give code, it will be nice if you put all lines where they should be.

Comment: that depends on your code structure if u provide me with your html may be i can help